# How to parse this nested JSON array and JSON object View_ID in android

Tags: java, android, json

> How to get `"View_ID":"v1"` and `View` Array.
>   **What I create is not generating the proper response. What thing I am doing wrong?**

Here is the response that I get:

```
{"success":true,"total":2,"View_ID":"v1","View":[{"id":"1","Button_ID":"acc123_b1","Publish_Topic":"\/ziniks\/acc123\/sw1","Subscribe_Topic":"\/ziniks\/acc123\/sw1_status"},{"id":"2","Button_ID":"acc123_b2","Publish_Topic":"\/ziniks\/acc123\/sw2","Subscribe_Topic":"\/ziniks\/acc123\/sw2_status"}]}
```

What I created to get Response:

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(response);
if(mainObj != null){
    JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("View");
    if(list != null){
        for(int j = 0; j < list.length();j++){
            JSONObject innerElem = list.getJSONObject(j);
            if(innerElem != null){
                String button_id = innerElem.getString("Button_ID");
                Toast.makeText(QRCode.this, button_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add `Log` in it.I try to use code.It's OK.And if add `if(response != null){
                
            }` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try bellow.


JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(response); if(mainObj != null){
    String viewid = mainObj.getString("View_ID");  // here is your View_ID.
     JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("View");  // here is your view array.

    if(list != null){ for(int j = 0; j < list.length();j++){ JSONObject innerElem = list.getJSONObject(j); if(innerElem != null){ String button_id = innerElem.getString("Button_ID"); Toast.makeText(QRCode.this, button_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } } } }
```